# Ember dynamic router redirect

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-router

I have the blow route in my route.js file

```
this.route('view', {path: 'view/:id'}, function() {
  this.route('page');
  this.route('detail');
});
```

When I call this from my index.js route file it's not working.

```
this.transitionTo('/view/123/page');
```

It stops in the browser like `/view/123` and the 'page' is not loaded. Can you anyone help me to resolve this.

Comment: transitionTo also will accept url. your code should work. Can you post any console errors ?. if there is no console error then please verify the page route and hbs files placed in the respective folder with same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont pass a path to `transitionTo`, but a route *name* and optional models.

So you can do this:

```
this.transitionTo('view.page', '123');
```